# error "...Was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

Este método privado `arbol_preorden` y el método público `consultar_individuo(string s)` pertenecen a la misma clase, llamada _Conjunto_Individuo_.

El caso es que me sale un error diciendo:

> Error: `consultar_individuo` was not declared in this scope.

Código:

```
list<string> arbol_preorden (Individuo& s){

    list<string> l;

    if (!s.tiene_progenitores()){
        l.insert(l.end(), "$");
    }
    else {
        string node = s.consultar_nombre();
        l = arbol_preorden (consultar_individuo (s.consultar_nombre_padre()));
        list<string> m;
        m = arbol_preorden(consultar_individuo(s.consultar_nombre_madre());
        l.insert(l.begin(),node);
        l.splice(l.end(),m);
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: comparte la clase completa por favor asi podemos entender que es lo que está mal

Comment: lo mas probable es que el método consultar_individuo no esté declarado en ese scope jaja

Comment: prueba con this